# Python Neural Network code 'Syntax Error: invalid syntax'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, syntax-error

I have a source code shows error whenever I try to run it. I've been tried to fix this many times but I couldn't find out the error. The console keep show this:

```
File "C:\Users\My Documents\LiClipse Workspace\ANN.py", line 51
print session.run(cost, feed_dict={X: x_data, Y: y_data})
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But still, I can't see any error..

Below are the chunk of code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool import xrange

x_data = np.array([
[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]
])

y_data = np.array([
[0],[1], [1], [0]
])

n_input = 2
n_hidden = 10
n_output = 1
learning_rate = 0.1
epochs = 1000

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n_input, n_hidden], -1.0, 1.0))
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n_hidden, n_output], -1.0, 1.0))

b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_hidden]), name="Bias1")
b2= tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_output]), name="Bias2")

L2 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, W1) + b1)
hy = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(L2, W2) + b2)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(-Y*tf.log(hy) - (1-Y)*tf.log(1-hy))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as session:
  session.run(init)

    for step in xrange(epochs):
        session.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x_data, Y: y_data})


        if step % 100 == 0:
            #print (cost)
            print session.run(cost, feed_dict={X: x_data, Y: y_data})


        answer = tf.equal(tf.floor(hy + 0.5), Y)
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(answer, "float"))

        print session.run([hy], feed_dict={X: x_data, Y: y_data})
        print "Accuracy: ", accuracy.eval({X: x_data, Y: y_data}) * 100, "%"
```

Can anyone tell me where I did wrongly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is tagged as Python 3.x, but the `print` statement is Python 2.0. Use `print(...)` function instead.

Comment: Sorry for silly question~ Anyway, I appreciate that.